# Using Date Range with FilterSet Django

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm trying to create a Date Range Filter , so this is my Model and filter:

```
class Caixa(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    data = models.DateField('Data')
    total = models.DecimalField('Total', decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True)
    unidade = models.ForeignKey(Unidade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Caixa " + self.unidade.nome

class CaixaFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    data_inicial = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='data', lookup_expr='gte'),
    data_final = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='data', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Caixa
        fields = ['data']
```

So, in my HTML i have the following:

```
<form method="get">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s6">
                    {% render_field filter.form.data_inicial class="datepicker" %}
                </div>
                <div class="col s6">
                    {% render_field filter.form.data_final class="datepicker" %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar
            </button>
        </form>
```

But only "**data_final**" field appear in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`DateFromToRangeFilter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#datefromtorangefilter) as,

```
import django_filters


class CaixaFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    data = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Caixa
        fields = ['data']
```

By that, you can use two keys, **`date_after`** and **`date_before`** to filter the date range.
**NOTE:** The suffix , **`after`** and **`before`** are belongs to **`django-filter==2.x`**

Comment: The problem with DateFromToRangeFilter is that I don't know if is possible separate Fields in different divs

Comment: I'm not good with forms. But, it's possible in DjangoRESTFramework. Anyway try it

Comment: Ok, but back to my question, why just one field appear? Is not strange?

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas Actually, I don't know :( Your snippet is working as expected in DRF. So, I assume, the problem may be in your template/form